# Can you guess the lock's passcode?

Tags: strategy

A lock's passcode is composed of three digits. Five incorrect passcodes are given below, each with a hint to the correct passcode.

**2-0-6:**
Two of the digits are correct but are in the wrong places.

**6-1-4:**
One of the digits is correct but is in the wrong place.

**6-8-2:**
One of the digits is correct and is in the right place.

**7-8-0:**
One digit is correct but is in the wrong place.

**7-3-8:**
None of the numbers is correct.

---

Can you deduce the lock's passcode?

Comment: Please stop asking these Social media forwarded questions

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 042

Just going step by step by eliminaion